# Use DTO or not?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao, dto

It seems to be very simple design question but I am curious of your opinions.

I have a DAO layer and one method returns both max and min value for something. So it returns two integer values but using as a return type `int[]` with two elements `int[0]=min_val` and `int[1]=max_val` is not very clear for the method caller, because he has to exactly know which element is first and which is the second.

Should I use here some kind of DTO like this...

```
class RangeValuesDTO {
  private int min_val;

  private int max_val;
}
```

?

What is the right pattern in such simple situation?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a DTO. A defining characteristic of a DTO is that it's an object used to transfer data that usually resides in another object - like a print-out of a file. The object here doesn't do that; it's just a perfectly normal value object (and using it seems like a great idea!).

Comment: Should I create additional package for vo objects... I mean... mypackages_structure.vo or should I use them inside dto packages or...? Im curious of good practices here when working with vos

Comment: I recommend packaging classes by domain rather than technical criteria. So, put the `Range` class in the same package as the DAO that produces it and the entity classes that that DAO works with.

Comment: hmmm maybe. but isn't it much more readable when you have separate package for vos like you usually have for model (entities). then you can quickly see what vo classes are available (if some new developer wants to reuse them). of course you can do it wherever your classes are. but for me is it much more readable when you have separate place for some kind of classes, like listeners, exceptions, model classes, daos, etc...

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste. I find that kind of organisation largely useless myself; i'd rather see functionally related classes together. Do whatever you find best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you should always wrap your data in meaningful and re-usable DataStructures.

Using DTO will help you in achieving that.

for example, in future if your DAO returns another `int` or `string` what will you do , If you use DTO the solution is simple to add that `int` or `string` to the DTO and not affecting other layers of the Application.

So +1 DTO

Answer (score 2):

You should ask yourself why you would need a certain pattern. There is no such a thing as best practice when it comes to enterprise patterns. Wrapping data structures from the db in an object to keep your interfaces tight and stable, as @TechExchange suggests, is a valid concern. But as @Tom Anderson points out, this should be rather called Value Object, not DTO.

And keep in mind that the need for the DTO pattern has some historical reasons (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object)) mainly in the pre-EJB-3-world. Those may not hold true anymore.

DTOs can help separating higher layers from accessing the data layer directly. In a simple CRUD application this can however add too much indirection and thus unnecessary duplication and complexity, thus more maintainance. You often end up having DTOs that look very similar to the entities that may not leave the data access layer.

DTOs can be especially helpful in distributed systems where they lead to more coarse grained interfaces and reduce network traffic.